# NSURLComponents builds scheme without //

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, nsurl

I'm trying to create an URL scheme to open the Tweetbot app in this way.

```
var urlComponents = NSURLComponents()
urlComponents.scheme = "tweetbot"
urlComponents.path = "BalestraPatrick/user_profile/\(user)"
```

My expected result would be: 
`tweetbot://BalestraPatrick/user_profile/username`

The result is instead: `tweetbot:BalestraPatrick/user_profile/username`

The // are not added automatically. If I try to add the characters to the scheme or to the path, the URL becomes nil.

Any idea for a workaround?

Comment: Assuming you're right about the desired form of a `tweetbot:` URL, then such URLs do not conform to RFC 3896 and therefore `NSURLComponents` isn't an appropriate class to use with them.

Comment: Very true, RFC 3986 says that `When authority is not present, the path cannot begin with two slash characters ("//")`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `//` won't appear if you don't specify `host`. I think the ideal solution would be:

```
let user = "test"

var urlComponents = NSURLComponents()
urlComponents.scheme = "tweetbot"
urlComponents.host = "BalestraPatrick"
urlComponents.path = "/user_profile/\(user)"

print("URL: \(urlComponents.string!)") // URL: tweetbot://BalestraPatrick/user_profile/test
```

Comment: Might work, might not. The rules for what's valid in a host are different from what's valid in a path. In any case, it's clearly a gross hack.

Comment: @KenThomases I was experimenting with various workarounds (e.g. `host = ""`) but the problem is that `NSURLComponents` don't allow path not to start with `/`, therefore you would end up with `tweetbot:///`. I think it's not a good behavior and maybe it would be easier to create just create a `NSURL` from a string.

Comment: Very hacky but it feels like the only solution without creating a NSURL. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

According to http://tapbots.net/tweetbot3/support/url-schemes/ the tweetbot URL scheme is in the form `tweetbot://<screenname>/<other_stuff>`.

So `tweetbot` is the URL's scheme, `<screenname>` is the URL's host, and `/<other_stuff>` is the URL's path and query.

So, the code in Sulthan's answer is absolutely correct (and not hacky).